# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common no cipher suites in common

Tags: java

Am trying to establish an SSL Connection between a client and a server. But anytime time i try to connect from my client, i get a **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common no cipher suites in common** error on my server. I have generated a keystore with signed certificates and i am referencing the keystore on both my client and server. I have gotten fed up after numerous research on this issue and related post on this site hasn't been helpful.

Here is my Server code

public class ServerApplicationSSL {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean debug = true;

    System.out.println("Waiting For Connection");

    int intSSLport = 4444;

    {
        Security.addProvider(new Provider());
        //Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:\\SSLCERT\\NEWAEDCKSSKYE");
        //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "skyebank");
    }
    if (debug) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
    }
    FileWriter file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileWriter("C:\\SSLCERT\\Javalog.txt");

    } catch (Exception ee) {
        //message = ee.getMessage();

    }

    try {

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\SSLCERT\\NEWAEDCKSSKYE"), "skyebank".toCharArray());
        file.write("Incoming Connection\r\n");

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keystore, "skyebank".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(keystore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) context.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(intSSLport);

        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();
        SSLServerSocket server_socket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocket;
        server_socket.setNeedClientAuth(true);

        sslSocket.startHandshake();

        System.out.println("Connection Accepted");
        file.write("Connection Accepted\r\n");

        while (true) {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslSocket.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            //while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println("Hello Client....Welcome");
            System.out.println("Hello Client....Welcome");
            //}

            out.close();
            //in.close();
            sslSocket.close();
            sslServerSocket.close();
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception exp) {
        try {
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage() + "\r\n");
            System.out.println(exp.getStackTrace() + "\r\n");
            file.write(exp.getMessage() + "\r\n");
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception eee) {
            //message = eee.getMessage();
        }

    }

}

}
```

Here is my clients code

```
public String MakeSSlCall(String meternum) {
    String message = "";
    FileWriter file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileWriter("C:\\SSLCERT\\ClientJavalog.txt");

    } catch (Exception ee) {
        message = ee.getMessage();
    }
    try {
        file.write("KeyStore Generated\r\n");
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\SSLCERT\\NEWAEDCKSSKYE"), "skyebank".toCharArray());
        file.write("KeyStore Generated\r\n");
        Enumeration enumeration = keystore.aliases();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            file.write("alias name: " + alias + "\r\n");
            keystore.getCertificate(alias);
            file.write(keystore.getCertificate(alias).toString() + "\r\n");
        }
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keystore, "skyebank".toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(keystore);
        file.write("KeyStore Stored\r\n");
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        KeyManager[] AllKeysMan = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        file.write("Key Manager Length is " + AllKeysMan.length + "\r\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < AllKeysMan.length; i++) {
            file.write("Key Manager At This Point is " + AllKeysMan[i] + "\r\n");
        }
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, null);
        SSLSocketFactory f = context.getSocketFactory();
        file.write("About to Connect to Ontech\r\n");
        SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("192.168.1.16", 4444);
        file.write("Connection Established to 196.14.30.33 Port: 8462\r\n");
        file.write("About to Start Handshake\r\n");
        c.startHandshake();
        file.write("Handshake Established\r\n");
        file.flush();
        file.close();
        return "Connection Established";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            file.write("An Error Occured\r\n");
            file.write(e.getMessage() + "\r\n");
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (Exception eee) {
            message = eee.getMessage();
        }
        return "Connection Failed";
    }
}
}
```

can someone please tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: I think what you are doing is wrong. For the client you need to create a trust store and import the server certificate into that. Could you please try that out? If you want I can give you a sample working code. Please do let me know.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I would really appreciate a sample working code

Comment: I have added some sample code with some suggestions as I understood in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use SSLContext for this purpose. Check out the sample code which I implemented in one of my applications below. Client context means you become the client and call some back end. Server context means you accept the client requests.

```
public class SSLUtil {
    private static String KEY_STORE_TYPE = "JKS";
    private static String TRUST_STORE_TYPE = "JKS";
    private static String KEY_MANAGER_TYPE = "SunX509";
    private static String TRUST_MANAGER_TYPE = "SunX509";
    private static String PROTOCOL = "TLS";

    private static SSLContext serverSSLCtx = null;
    private static SSLContext clientSSLCtx = null;

    public static SSLContext createServerSSLContext(final String keyStoreLocation,
                                                    final String keyStorePwd)
                                                                             throws KeyStoreException,
                                                                             NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                                                                             CertificateException,
                                                                             FileNotFoundException,
                                                                             IOException,
                                                                             UnrecoverableKeyException,
                                                                             KeyManagementException {
        if (serverSSLCtx == null) {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE);
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreLocation), keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KEY_MANAGER_TYPE);
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
            serverSSLCtx = SSLContext.getInstance(PROTOCOL);
            serverSSLCtx.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        }

        return serverSSLCtx;
    }

    public static SSLContext createClientSSLContext(final String trustStoreLocation,
                                                    final String trustStorePwd)
                                                                               throws KeyStoreException,
                                                                               NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                                                                               CertificateException,
                                                                               FileNotFoundException,
                                                                               IOException,
                                                                               KeyManagementException {
        if (clientSSLCtx == null) {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(TRUST_STORE_TYPE);
            trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStoreLocation), trustStorePwd.toCharArray());
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =
                                                      TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TRUST_MANAGER_TYPE);
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
            clientSSLCtx = SSLContext.getInstance(PROTOCOL);
            clientSSLCtx.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        }

        return clientSSLCtx;

    }

}
```

Finally make sure you import the trusted server certificate to the client key store. Literally server and client should have different key stores. The key store used in the client side is referred to as client trust store since we are trusting the server certificate here. [This article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html) may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am no longer getting the cipher suite error. i think it was because i was referencing the same keystore in my server and client. However i am now getting this execption on my server   "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown" and this exception on my client "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found"

Comment: Did you import the server certificate to your client trust store using the key tool import command? Check this out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/rstep1.html

Comment: Yes i have. i use this command when creating a truststore for my client
keytool -import -alias skyebankaedc -file skyebankaedc.cer -keystore mycerts -storepass skyebank and also run this command to import my own certificate  keytool -import -alias mucert -file mucert.cer -keystore mycerts -storepass myccert

Comment: I also run the same commands when creating and importing certificates into the keystore of my server